# ссылка на дженерик

Tags: java, generics

```
List<String> i = new ArrayList<>();
List i2 = i;
i2.add(new MyClass());
```

Почему такая запись функционирует? i2 уже ждет object в параметрах add, а не стринги. От чего это происходит?

Comment: Так а отчего i2 должен ждать не object, а String?

Comment: ну он ссылается на дженерик с типом стринг, либо он их воспринимает, либо ошибку выдает, так как я не создавал других объектов с другими типами.

Comment: Возможно просто i2 приводи i к object, так как всё равно все типы идёт от него. имхо.

Comment: Ну смотрите, попробую сказать просто. Ваш объект List<String> i - содержит дженерик, и т.о. "сужен". Когда вы объявляете i2, то вы создаёте объект интерфейса List <Object> и он и остаётся в памяти таким, однако и ссылается на тип <String>.

Ведь если бы это было не так, то вы не смогли бы сделать так:

List <String> i4 = new ArrayList<>();
List <Integer> i5 = new ArrayList<>();

List i2 = i4; //по вашему он уже стринг и бесповоротно таков
List i2 = i5; //но нет, так возможно

Comment: Кстати говоря, а вы пробовали наблюдать наоборот - List<String> присвоить List?

Comment: @ИванХорошевский, ну то что он приводит в object, это факт, мне интересно именно его поведение, точнее почему так происходит.

Comment: list это интерфейс, как его объект создам?

Comment: Элементарно. Вот как вы создали List i2, так же можете создать объект и любого другого интерфейса. Законом не запрещено

Comment: тогда я не понял вашего ответа, я же не могу написать List<String> = new List<String>();.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78319/discussion-between--and-bulbum).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И так у вас есть объект с типом `ArrayList<>`;

И у вас есть две ссылки `i == List<String>; i2 == List`

В этот конкретный объект вы можете добавить абсолютно любой тип.
Но первой ссылкой `i List<String>` вы добавили ограничение типом `String`;
Соответственно используя ссылку `i` вы сможете добавлять только объекты типа `String`

Следующим шагом вы добавляете еще одну ссылку `i2` на объект `new ArrayList<>`, которая уже не имеет ограничений. Соответственно, используя эту ссылку вы можете добавить переменные любого типа.

Comment: тогда по какой причине он игнорит то,  что я его присвоил к джинерику с однозначно объявленным типом.

Comment: я не вызываю new ArrayList<> второй раз, я ссылаюсь на уже созданный объект. По этой причине возникает ситуация, что я ссылаюсь на объект с типом джинерика стрингов, а могу создавать объект любого другого типа.

Comment: при этом если я вызываю i2.get(0), то мне выводить инфу об MyClass, а если напишу i.get(0), то компилятор пишет что не может привести один тип к другому. То есть обе переменные знают о вставленном значение, но i, не может его вызвать.

Comment: У вас объект без типа дженерика! Где вы ссылаетесь на объект с типом дженерика стринг??? Вы используете ссылку с типом дженерика стринг а объект у вас как был `ArrayList` так и остался

Comment: объект создается ключевым словом new, List i2, это просто переменная. Где вы увидели у i2, ключевое слово new ? или я что-то не догоняю ?

Comment: правильно вот и я не догоняю где вы увидели `new ArrayList<String>` Вы создали один объект и две ссылки(переменные)

Comment: ну так да ))) если я ссылаюсь на один объект который является string, могу даже так написать, если угодно List<String> i = new ArrayList<String>(); То почему вторая переменная которая ссылается на этот же джинерик позволяет понижать тип на Object, почему на нее не действует это ограничение в String ?

Comment: @Алексей потому что непараметризированный лист может быть чем угодно. Сейчас вы написали <String>, а следующей строкой может быть <Integer> что тогда ?

Comment: @Алексей потому что тип второй переменной такой

Comment: @JVic ну так почему он не может понять, что раз я ссылаюсь на стринговый джинерик, наверное я хочу чтобы он был тоже стрингом, тогда ему и гадать не придется какого типа будет List в следующий строке

Comment: Еще раз вы НЕ ССЫЛАЕТЕСЬ на стринговый дженерик! вы ссылаетесь напростой эрейлист, есть два разных понятия тип объекта и тип ссылки!

Comment: @JVic окей я ссылаюсь на просто arraylist, у которого тип во всех его полях и методах уже string, вопроса это не изменила, почему вторая переменная не подгоняет тип своего джинерика под типы джинерика указанного выше.

Comment: @Алексей потому что это язык такой. зачем подгонять если вы это можете сделать руками? нужен вам тип стринг так укажите его! А если вы объявили лист без указания типа то пользуйтесь обыкновенным листом

Comment: Действительно. А зачем неявное приведение типов? зачем автоупакова? если я могу это делать руками. Дело как раз в том почему так решили оставить, для какой-то гибкости или для других нужд. Если это не несло бы нагрузки, сделали бы автоматическим.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78323/discussion-between-jvic-and-).